# Jetpack Compose Textfield Alignment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to jetpack compose. I want to start typing from TextField's centervertically-start
position but I can't put "Example" to center
vertically-start position.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(50.dp)
        .shadow(5.dp)
        .background(Color.Yellow),


) {

    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {onvalueChange(it)},
        modifier = Modifier.weight(10f).background(Color.Blue).fillMaxSize(),
        singleLine = true,
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )


    )
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_search_24),
        contentDescription = "Search",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(2f).fillMaxSize()

    )
```

This is my code

[image: image1]

And this is what I want to do.

[image: image2]

Comment: you need to increase font size of your text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row` has a `verticalAlignment` for this. Also, if you want your TextField left align like the picture, remove the `textAlign` (or change it but it default to start)

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(50.dp)
        .shadow(5.dp)
        .background(Color.Yellow),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
) {

    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {onvalueChange(it)},
        modifier = Modifier.weight(10f).background(Color.Blue).fillMaxSize(),
        singleLine = true,
    )
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_search_24),
        contentDescription = "Search",
        modifier = Modifier.weight(2f).fillMaxSize()

    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried it before and it doesn't work. If I do this  I am  typing to "start-top" position. I want to start typing to "start-centervertically".

Comment: It's because you're using `fillMaxSize` on both your composables. If your image is bigger (likely is given what you're experiencing), then your `TextField` takes more height than needed

Comment: How can I fill row's height with BasicTextField? I tried fillMaxSize and it doesnt work as you said.

Comment: Replace your `BasicTextField` with a `TextField` and you're good to go :)

Comment: It's worked thank you. Can you tell me why basictextfield is not working?

Comment: Never used that component before, you can see the source code and navigate in it easily. I'd say it doesn't handle gravity the same way – although gravity is no longer a concept when it comes to compose

Answer (score 2):

Use background box to control, please try:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(50.dp)
    .shadow(5.dp)
    .background(Color.Yellow),
    ) {
        Box(Modifier.weight(10f).background(Color.Blue).fillMaxSize(),contentAlignment = CenterStart){
            BasicTextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { onvalueChange(it) },
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(
                    Alignment.CenterVertically),
                singleLine = true,
                textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                )
            )
        }
        Image(
            Icons.Filled.Search,
            contentDescription = "Search",
            modifier = Modifier.weight(2f).fillMaxSize()
    
        )
    }
```

Comment: This is working too but basictextfield doesn't fill inside of box. There are spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Modifier.padding also works for OutlinedTextField.

```
OutlinedTextField(
                value = textInput,
                 onValueChange = { onvalueChange(it) },
modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    .padding(top = 5.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
```